# CMake project in Visual Studio 2017 not rebuilding after first build

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I have a project of roughly 50 files that I build with the CMake integration in Visual Studio 2017 (latest release, version 15.0.0+26228.9).

If I regenerate my CMake cache and then build, my project is built normally. However, if I change something in one of my files, then try to rebuild without regenerating my CMake cache, nothing happens.

This is what the build window looks like:

```
Build started ...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Nothing will be built until I regenerate my CMake cache, where I will only be able to build once before getting the same issue.

Same issue happens on any CMake project I try to build. This issue only started happening on the latest full release of Visual Studio 2017, this did not happen in the RC builds.

Comment: Latest version of CMake?

Comment: Yep, just upgraded to 3.8.0-rc2 from 3.7.2 and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Works for me. Can you please give an [mcve]?

Comment: @Florian Sure. [Here is a new project with the necessary files shown.](https://gist.github.com/Bumrang/5c4c91e085a7c7283a3b24e18f171549) Still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up repairing the Visual Studio 2017 install from the Visual Studio installer and that fixed it. Everything works as intended now.